# Auto Fill Data When Edit Post in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hello I'm totally new for ruby on rails, so please friends, explain it as much as u can. Well I have create a post and category MVC, now i added category:references in Post Model, everything working fine.

When I'm create a post with all the data everything publish too with category. But now when i'm editing post again, category data is not filling, while when i create a post i fill category in Post article. So please tell me how to add code to auto fill category when i m editing post article. [image: scrrenshot posts/new]

Thanks a lot

Comment: Here is the example, when i'm editing post, category again black while category have 5 fi


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/clivl.png

Comment: In category model u have has_many :posts, in posts model belongs_to :category, in posts table u hav category_id field. Is that all present there. what is ur code in views/posts/new.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb

```
@current_category = Category.find(params[:id])
@categories = Category.all
```

/app/views/posts/edit.html.erb

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <%= category.id %> <br />
  <% if category.id == @current_category.id %>
    current
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Then you can add your select html and make current category selected

Comment: Thanks to reply, well neeraj First of all, I'm using inherit_resources gem, So I don't need to mention these code, but after read ur code I notice that, I forgot to mention cateogry_id in permitted_params. Now Its working fine thanks